# Function with many variables and with if statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, calculator

I'm designing a web calculator and now have four `input type="number"`, each with a value.

I have the `range` with `span` (where the value is displayed). The `sumUpNewCar` function sums all the `input` values and displays the value in `id="showPr"`.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("pr");
var output = document.getElementById("showPr");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value + "%";
}

function sumUpNewCar() {
  var promoLoan = document.getElementById("newAuto1").value;
  var standardLoan = document.getElementById("newAuto2").value;
  var promoPlusLoan = document.getElementById("newAuto3").value;
  var standardPlusLoan = document.getElementById("newAuto4").value;
  var penetrationLoan = document.getElementById("showPr"); /* doesn't work */
  var sumPromoLoans = document.getElementById("sumPromoLoans").innerHTML = (promoLoan * Number(0.004)) + (promoPlusLoan * Number(0.0004));
  var sumStandardLoans = document.getElementById("sumStandardLoans").innerHTML = (standardLoan * 0.07) + Math.round(standardPlusLoan * 0.028);
  var sumNewVehicle = document.getElementById("sumNewVehicle").innerHTML = sumPromoLoans + sumStandardLoans;
  var overallPromo = sumPromoLoans.value;

  /* doesnt work*/
  if (penetrationLoan > 24.99 && penetrationLoan < 35) {
    overallPromo *= 0.005;
  }
}

/*
else if(penetrationLoan >= 35){
    sumPromoLoans * Number(0.01);
    sumStandardLoans * Number(0.02);
}
else if(penetrationLoan >=25 <=29.99){
    sumStandardLoans * Number(0.01);
 }
 else if(penetrationLoan >=30 <=34.99){
    sumStandardLoans * Number(0.015);
 } else {
    sumNewVehicle * Number(1);
 }

}
*/
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
  <form>
    <input class="promo" type="number" min="1000" max="100000000" id="newAuto1" onchange="sumUpNewCar()">
    <input class="standard" type="number" min="100000" max="100000000" id="newAuto2" onchange="sumUpNewCar()">
    <input class="promoPlus" type="number" min="100000" max="100000000" id="newAuto3" onchange="sumUpNewCar()">
    <input class="standardPlus" type="number" min="100000" max="100000000" id="newAuto4" onchange="sumUpNewCar()">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="mainbox2">
  <div class="newvehicle2"><b>bonus</b></div>
  <input type="range" min="20" max="40" step="1" class="slider" value="20" id="pr">
  <div class="showPr"><span class="showPr2" id="showPr" onchange="sumUpNewCar()"> </span> </div>
  <div class="mainbox6">
    <div class="overall"></div>
    <table class="tableOverall">
      <tr>
        <td id="sumNewVehicle"></td>
        <td id="sumPromoLoans"></td>
        <td id="sumStandardLoans"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="sumUsedVehicle"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="sumSpr"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="sumPrs"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="sumUp"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

**NEW**

Finally, I changed for:

```
penetrationLoan=document.getElementById("pr").value
```

and put:

```
<input type="range" min="20" max="40" step="1" class="slider" value="20" id="pr" onchange="sumUpNewCar()">
```

And it hasn't still worked.

Comment: What is the question? You are not doing anything with overallpromo

Comment: *"doesnt work"* doesn't tell us what the specific problem is or expected behavior and doesn't indicate if errors are encountered

Comment: You have an onchange on a span. that will never work - perhaps you meant `penetrationLoan=document.getElementById("pr").value`

Comment: "showPr" is a div tag. You are trying to compare that object to number literals. That "doesn't work"

Comment: sorry, the question is "Why this part of the function doesn't work?" if (penetrationLoan > 24.99 && penetrationLoan < 35) {
    overallPromo *= 0.005;

Comment: You for sure need `penetrationLoan=document.getElementById("pr").value` before anything

Comment: Finally, I changed for `penetrationLoan=document.getElementById("pr").value` and put `<input type="range" min="20" max="40" step="1" class="slider" value="20" id="pr" onchange="sumUpNewCar()">` . And it hasn't still worked(((